# Why Magento uiRegistry not list some UI Component?

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent

**Field Create Code**

```
   $data = [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'component' => 'vendor_module/js/form/element/ui-select-mixin',
                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                    'dataScope' => {data_scope},
                    'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                    'disableLabel' => true,
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select',
                    'filterOptions' => true,
                    'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                    'label' => __('Label:'),
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'options' => $this->getOptions(),
                    'selectedPlaceholders' => [
                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'defaultPlaceholder' => __('None'),
                    ],
                    'validation' => [
                        'required-entry' => false
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

**Mixin Component Code**

vendor_module/js/form/element/ui-select-mixin

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select',
    'uiLayout'
], function ($, _, registry, UiSelect) {
    'use strict';

    return UiSelect.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            //Some Lines of Code
            return this._super();
        }
    });
});
```

**Field on Admin Form**

[image]

So I am trying to access all the fields of that form in JS using **uiRegistry**. but when i print the field key in the console it is not there. Other fields key was printed like **Checkbox, Text Area, Image**. here is the code.

```
define([
    'uiElement',
    'uiRegistry'
], function (Element, registry) {
    'use strict';

    return Element.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            registry.filter(function(value, key) {
                console.log(key);
            });

            return this;
        },
    });
});
```

I want to get the value of all **Select Field** and Show at the particular **Container**. The above JS code is for **Container Component**.

If someone has a different way then also please comment.

**Note: The Select Field is in Dyanamic Raw**

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 JS loads after the body is loaded. So whenever the page is loaded, the scripts are loaded simultaneously. You can try something like:

```
require(['jquery'],
    function ($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                  $('select[name="custom_attr_name"]').change(function () {
                      alert($(this).val());
                  });
              },5000);
    });
})
```

Or if it does not works try using body load inside the ready() function.

Answer (score -1):

List all components

```
var registry = require('uiRegistry');
registry.filter(function(value, key) {
    console.log(key);
    // console.log(value); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did the same thing you can check on the question.