# How we get an element from second tab of ui component on edit magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an Admin UI form with two tabs. There is a dropdown field on first tab .Based on this dropdown value I want to show or hide an another field which appeared on the second tab. But we could not hide this field. I just log this field on console but I got undefined value. But it works on onchange scenario.

Any one please help [image: Admin form screenshot]

Comment: have you checked with uiRegistry?

Comment: Yes it doesn't work. Actually it is fieldset.
I tried,
var banner = uiRegistry.get('index = banner');
banner.hide();
But I got 'Uncaught TypeError: banner.hide is not a function'

Comment: have you check is field appearing on the uiRegistry or not like this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351823/78648

Comment: yes it is appeared on the uiRegistry
'block_sliders_form.areas.items.items.banner'

Comment: you can get it as uiRegistry.get('block_sliders_form.areas.items.items.banner');   

you can see in documentation

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/concepts/registry/

Comment: yes I tried this but I got the same js error 'Uncaught TypeError: banner.hide is not a function'